# Objective-C call C function - linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: objective-c, c, function, linker-errors

I have the following header file

```
typedef enum {
    MONDAY = 1,
    TUESDAY = 2,
    WEDNESDAY = 3,
    THURSDAY = 4,
    FRIDAY = 5,
    SATURDAY = 6,
    SUNDAY = 7,
} WeekDaysEnum;



NSString* dayToString(WeekDaysEnum theDay)
{
    switch (theDay) {        
        case MONDAY:
            return @"Monday";
            break;

        case TUESDAY:
            return @"Tuesday";
            break;

        case WEDNESDAY:
            return @"Wednesday";
            break;

        case THURSDAY:
            return @"Thursday";
            break;

        case FRIDAY:
            return @"Friday";
            break;

        case SATURDAY:
            return @"Saturday";
            break;

        case SUNDAY:
            return @"Sunday";
            break;
    }
}
```

For some the function `dayToString` causes the following error:

```
linker command failed with exit code 1
```

How can I call `dayToString` function within Objective-C `.m` file ?

Comment: Is your function itself in the header file?

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, the enum and the function are in a header file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the function from the header to a separate source file or declare it as `inline`.